# Prophet and weights contradiction

Tags: r, regression, time-series, python, prophet

I'm using Prophet to forecast sales. The training set is based on years 2013 to 2016 included and the 1st half of 2017 is used for validation.
I've noticed the sales drop during the New Year day (likely stores are closed). The problem is that Prophet does not predict a close-to-zero value for that day in 2017 even if a holiday effect is added. You can see the forecasts below.

[image]

The reason comes from that fact that the 1st Jan of 2017 is a Sunday which has a strong positive weight that cancel a part of the negative new year weight.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can make Prophet outputs a close-to-zero value on new year ? I would like to avoid adding a post-processing step with handmade rules if possible.

Comment: So the rest of the forecast is satisfactory but you worry about this single date? Then why not just wrap Prophet‘s predict function with `if new_year then 0 else predict()`?

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the answer. If possible, I'd like to avoid any post-processing. But the main reason is that other "contradictions" might exist. This one is only easy to notice, the rest of the forecast might not be satisfactory.